# Right Triangle within another right triangle inside a square

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, triangles

As you can see in the below picture, We have a right triangle inside a big square, and within the triangle there is another small right triangle.

The question as follows: Find the length of `AB` "With" using `BE` and `FG`in your solution.

Well I came up with this question because I need to find `AB` without using the other data that we can simply take them from the image, because I am working in a project That I must use raycasting method anyway after analyzing and a lot of drawing I managed to answer the question as follows :

[image]

We have `BE = 4cm` and `FG = 0.5cm` then `AB = BE / FG` => `AB = 4 / 0.5` => `AB = 8cm`

and I found this method works only if the `AE` ray stays within the square area, For example if point `E = (10,8)` this method will not work anymore as shown below :

[image]

there is some area of the triangle is outside the square and also if you see the picture you will find that `FG` now is big than 1 cm `FG > 1cm`, so this method will work for you just if `FG > 0 && FG <= 1`

I believe that there is another way to explain this so my question is does anyone knows the logic behind `AB = BE / FG` or someone who knows a better explanation or some formulas that works with this kind of triangles.

## Edit

after Daniel Mathias answered my question, I realized even the second example the "method" works with it, i just got confused with another triangle my bad.

Comment: Use Thales Proportionally Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles $ABE$ and $AFG$ are similar, with $\frac{AB}{BE}=\frac{AF}{FG}$. Given $AF=1$, this means:

$$\frac{AB}{BE}=\frac{1}{FG}\implies AB=\frac{BE}{FG}$$

This is true without exception. In your second image, you have $BE=10$, $FG=1.25$ and $AB=\frac{10}{1.25}=8$.

Comment: you are a life saver bro, I know that we study Thales Proportionally Theorem back in school i just forgot the name until @Ripi2 commented it, but you know when you stay away from math for several years you just forget it.